# DateTime to NSDate

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nsdate

How do I convert string `2010-11-19T20:00:00Z` into an `NSDate` object?

I've tried using `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"]` but it looks like I got the wrong custom format style.

PS: I don't care about Timezones. Actually, I want the date to stay in the original (UTC) timezone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using your format string to convert *from* an NSDate *to* a string and see what you get. It's easier debugging in that direction than the other.

In this case, looks as though you need to escape the T and Z literals in your pattern. Something like this:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
```