# Converting ex. 2010-09-11T00:00:00+01:00 format to NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate

I have spent way too much time (over an hour) on what I though would be a two minute task.
On the iPhone:

```
NSString * dateString = @"2010-09-11T00:00:00+01:00";
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssTZD"];
NSDate  *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

RESULT: date == nil

What am I missing!! (Besides my deadline)

Regards,

Ken

Comment: haha, I've posted exactly the same question 10min ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179993

Answer (score 13, accepted):

TZD isn't a defined formatter per [the unicode spec](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date%5FFormat%5FPatterns). The document you've linked to elsewhere was a suggestion someone made to W3C, for discussion only. The unicode standard followed by Apple is a finished standard, from a different body.

The closest thing to what you want would be ZZZ (ie, @"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"), but that doesn't have a colon in the middle. So you'd need to use the string:

```
2010-09-11T00:00:00+0100
```

Rather than the one you currently have that ends in +01:00.

E.g. the following:

```
NSString * dateString = @"2010-09-11T00:00:00+0100";
NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
NSDate  *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"%@", date);
```

Logs a valid date object, of 2010-09-10 23:00:00 GMT.

Comment: Thanks for that.  As I am getting time codes in two formats ...+01:00 AND ...Z i.e. 2010-09-11T00:00:00Z, just had to add remove the colon from the +00:00 time code and check for Z in the case it was not present and change code to  YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ in that case. -- Confusing sentence, but its late, I'm tired...Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Tip: try using your formatter to convert *from* an NSDate object *to* a string, then see what you get. It's often easier to debug in that direction than the other.

Have you read this?

http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns

That TZD at the end of your format string looks a bit dodgy.

Comment: That's a different standard from the one NSDateFormatter uses. Have a look at the unicode.org link.

Answer (score -2):

I solved this issue using [this](http://code.google.com/r/icetreay-beta/source/browse/Extensions/XEP-0082/?r=ada2c87b24cab5f027cd495ba25abd813673798c) code.